# How to read Chart from Excel sheet using java?

Tags: java, excel, charts

I have used jxl library to read excelsheet and it works fine for String and Numbers but now I also want to read Chart from that excel sheet. As I don''t know how to read Chart using this library. can anyone tell me, how do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/). This is the best as per my experience. I was able to grab some  information from Excel2007 charts, few years ago. Apache POI should have more and more options by now.

You may able to use [XSSFChartSheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFChartSheet.html), [XSLFChart](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFChart.html), ...etc classes.

Read these as well.

[How to get chart info from an Excel spreadsheet using Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599304/how-to-get-chart-info-from-an-excel-spreadsheet-using-apache-poi)

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/

[Apache POI Limitations](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html)

Comment: Thanx :) 
I have read about Apache POI but is it possible to do same with jxl library ?

Comment: I don't think so. Here is good answer for your question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980717/what-is-the-better-api-to-reading-excel-sheets-in-java-jxl-or-apache-poi