# Copy paste contents of excel into outlook

Tags: java, excel, outlook, apache-poi

I have an excel sheet with one of the sheet as 'summary' which has summary of the execution, I am using javax mail to send this excel as attachment using outlook, however I would like to paste this summary in the email body so users get a summary before opening the excel.
I have tried with opening the excel and capturing the screen shot but whole excel is captured I only need whats inside excel.
I dont want to use VBA as the excel sheet may change.

Below is the code I am using for sending email:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;
    import javax.mail.Multipart;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class EmailExecutionReport {
 static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
 static Date date = new Date();


 static String attachFiles="C:\\Excel_Report.xls";
 static String messageToBeSent="<body > <p><font face="+"calibri"+">Hi All,</font></p><p><font face="+"calibri"+">Please find the Environment validations report as in the attached file</font></p><p><font face="+"calibri"+">This set of execution was completed on: "+dateFormat.format(date)+"</font></p><br><font face="+"calibri"+">Regards<br><font face="+"calibri"+"><br><br>---This is a auto generated email---</body>";
 @Test
public static void JavaSentEamil() throws IOException {
   // String host="host";  

    final String user="SSS@abcd.com"; 
    String to="icpm-qa@abcd.com";


    //Get the session object  
    Properties props = new Properties();  
    props.put("mail.smtp.host","abcd.abcd.com");  
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");

    Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    session.setDebug(true);

    //Compose the message  
    try {
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.saveChanges();
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));  
        //message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress (to));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
        message.setSubject("Automation Environment validations Report as on: "+dateFormat.format(date));  
       // message.setText("This is test mail sent from Java Program");  
        // creates message part
        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setContent(messageToBeSent, "text/html ; charset=ISO-8859-1");

        // creates multi-part
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        // adds attachments
        if (attachFiles != null) {
                              MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                         attachPart.attachFile(attachFiles);
                    multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
                } 
         // sets the multi-part as e-mail's content
        message.setContent(multipart);

        //send the message
        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Message sent successfully...");
    }
    catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are not using Excel POI and using the ChartSheet object there. But just to give you an idea here is already an existing discussion

[How to get chart info from an Excel spreadsheet using Apache POI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599304/how-to-get-chart-info-from-an-excel-spreadsheet-using-apache-poi)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have used robot of java to capture the screen shot of summary section and pasted it inline in outlook email